# Set value of hidden html label in php

Tags: php

I wish to change the value of html hidden label to a value of php variable. . And set its visibility to true. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You want to have a *visible hidden*  label? Please explain.

Comment: I wish to show error message to user after server side validations are done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $errorMessage = "Yes, there was an error";

?>

...

<?php
    if ($errorMessage) {
        print("<p>$errorMessage</p>");
    }
?>
```

I hate PHP so much.

Comment: Actually I want to display the error message using label after server side validation are done. Can anyone elaborate on it?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer. It's a pretty simple check to see if the error message exists. If so, then display the label.

Comment: can it be done with labels? Because i want to change the visibility of label when user changes the input text after error was displayed

Answer (score 1):

if you want to block the visibility of a form field, you should mark it as `type="hidden"`

Comment: Actually I want to display the error message using label after server side validation are done. Can anyone elaborate on it?

Answer (score 0):

### Labels cannot be hidden, unless CSS is used.

#### To hide an element by default, use `hidden` element as

```
<input type="hidden" />
```

In case of using CSS is acceptable

CSS

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

PHP

```
<?php $labelvalue = "somevalue"; ?>
<label for="someinput" name="somename" class="hidden"><?php echo $labelvalue; ?></label>
```